# c# drawpolygon() как рисовать несколько фигур

Tags: c#, графика, рисование

как с помощью DrawPolygon рисовать так, чтобы при рисовании новой фигуры не пропадала старая?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Рисую первую фигуру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Рисую вторую, пропадает первая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> ```
> using (var PenP = new Pen(Color.Black, 0.1f))
>         using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
>         {
>
>
>             if (Class1.CheckPoint() != null)
>             {
>                 
>                 
>                 int i = Class1.CheckPoint()[0];
>                 int j = Class1.CheckPoint()[1];
>                 int cp = Class1.CheckPoint()[2];
>
>                 if(cp == 1){
>                     PenP.Color = Color.Red;
>                     brush.Color = Color.IndianRed;
>                     Point[] a = { new Point(i, j), new Point(i + 1, j), new Point(i + 1, j + 1), new Point(i, j + 1) };
>                     e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, a);
>                     e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(PenP, a);
>                 
>
>                 }
>                 if (cp == 2)
>                 {
>                     PenP.Color = Color.Blue;
>                     brush.Color = Color.RoyalBlue;
>                     Point[] a = { new Point(i, j), new Point(i + 1, j), new Point(i + 1, j + 1), new Point(i, j + 1) };
>                     e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, a);
>                     e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(PenP, a);                        
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Ошибка за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: Вы наверное где-то во внешнем цикле фигуры перебираете и неправильно вызываете отрисовку.

Comment: @Blackmeser у меня идет проверка в функции CheckPoint, когда 4 точки одинакового цвета составляют квадрат, а отрисовка уже как раз на скрине.

Comment: @DrGlide ну в данном куске кода ошибки не видно.

Comment: @Blackmeser я так понял мне нужно как-то добавлять каждый отрисованный элемент в список чтобы оно сохранялось, но не знаю как это сделать

Comment: @DrGlide вам нужно придумать унивесальный базовый класс/абстрактный класс/интерфейс, хранящий некоторые параметры (свойства) для отрисовки и метод вызова отрисовки, принимающий Graphics в качестве одного из аргументов, описывающие рисуемый объект, ещё у вас должен быть список элементов с вашим типом класса, когда вы хотите добавить/удалить/изменить элемент, вы добавляете его в список и вызываете метод обновления холста (напр. panel.invalidate) и в методе panel_paint обходите список и вызываете методы отрисовки, передавая им Graphics, внутри методов вы выполняете саму отрисовку этого элемента.